# c# Progress bar with backgroundworker

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a progress bar in UI, I want to change its progress with the execution of each functions until the end. I have tried with background worker. I am trying to implement using backgroundworker_dowork function. How can I sync it with my ongoing functionality. Right now do work just takes the initial progress. How can I increase it with every function execution.

My code is something like this:

```
private  void  Ok_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    //set max sixe of progress bar
        elementForm.progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        //// To report progress from the background worker we need to set this property
        elementForm.backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        //// This event will be raised on the worker thread when the worker starts
        elementForm.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);

        //// This event will be raised when we call ReportProgress
        elementForm.backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
       elementForm.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
method1();
progress=10;
method2();
progress=20
method3();
lastmethod();
progress=100;

}
```

basically progress should increase along with the method execution. every method is doing something that should increase progress and after the last method called progress should be 100%.

code for backgroundWorker1_DoWork (what should I do here to sync the progress increment with methods completion)

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        if (elementForm.progressBar1.Value < elementForm.progressBar1.Maximum)
        {
            while(progress!=100)
            {

                elementForm.progressBar1.Increment(progress);

                elementForm.progressBar1.CreateGraphics().DrawString(progress.ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new PointF(elementForm.progressBar1.Width / 2 - 10, elementForm.progressBar1.Height / 2 - 7));


            }
        }
    }
```

code for backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged:

```
        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,
           ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (elementForm.InvokeRequired)
        {
            elementForm.Invoke(new Action<object, ProgressChangedEventArgs>(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged), sender, e);

            return;
        }

        // The progress percentage is a property of e
        elementForm.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

    }
```

Comment: please insert some codes to show your what you've done.

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: Look at the related column on the right here. There are dozens of similar questions on this site. What makes your question different?

Comment: Show code which you tried before.

Comment: hello all, can you please check the modified question now?

Comment: Find a good example,  plenty of them out there. method1() should be in DoWork(), not in OnClick(). Inside ProgressChanged() you don't need to Invoke. Various pieces are not thread-safe.

Comment: You should not call `CreateGraphics` in that manner, because you are never disposing the `Graphics` instance that is getting created, resulting in a leak.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments.

I placed my functionality in Do_work and my progress bar monitors and runs in sync with the function calls inside Do_work.